# How to connect my android app to a matlab script & get the result back on the app?

Tags: android, matlab, server

I am working on a project where I need to send the audio recorded by my android app to a Matlab script, do the processing, and send the result back. The recorded audio is saved in firebase storage. I can use the download link of a file from firebase for Matlab to run. But I don't know how to send that link to Matlab. I'm hoping to achieve this on my local server i.e my own computer.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Yes, this is [possible](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/communicate-using-tcpip-server-sockets.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)

Comment: This is an other option: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlwrite.html

Comment: I don't think urlwrite does the job. I need the results back on my app. I don't know which exact tool to pick, can xampp work? And how?

Comment: Can I use webwrite to save data in Firebase?